# Returning an ArrayList from a method by using volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to return arrayList , when i return arrayList is empty. I will use when i return arrayList but Its not working.

```
 public ArrayList<Cities> getCities(){
    final ArrayList<Cities> cities=new ArrayList<>();
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/cities";
    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("city");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject city = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String id = city.getString("_id");
                            String name = city.getString("name");
                            Cities p=new Cities(id,name);
                            cities.add(p);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mQueue.add(request);
return cities;
}
```

Comment: Should be something like `public void getCities(SuccessCallback<ArrayList<Cities>> successCallback) {` where success callback is `public interface SuccessCallback<T> { void onSuccess(T t); }`

Comment: The return from `getCities` occurs before you ever get a response in `onResponse`.  The volley request/response is asynchronous to your `getCities` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your response returns a JSONObject with a City element array of cities, your request is correct, but as mentioned above, you can't expect to actually have the results until the callback is called.  Here is an example that uses a JSONArrayRequest which returns a JSONArray, but pretty much works the same way as yours after you have extracted the City array out of the JSONObject.

```
    private ListView mTripList;
public ArrayList<TripItem> tripItems;
private JSONArray unclaimedTrips;
private TripSelectAdapter adapter;



public void getTrips() {

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray> () {  

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            // Public Array
            unclaimedTrips = response;

            tripItems = new ArrayList<TripItem>();


            // Optional if you want to manipulate the data in some way
            if (unclaimedTrips != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < unclaimedTrips.length(); i++) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject item = unclaimedTrips.getJSONObject(i);

                        int tripID = item.getInt("trip_id");
                        int claimID = item.getInt("claim_id");
                        String payrollCode = item.getString("payroll_code");
                        String tripDate = item.getString("trip_date");
                        String tripPurpose = item.getString("trip_purpose");

                        TripItem tripItem = new TripItem(tripID, claimID, payrollCode, tripDate, tripPurpose);

                        tripItems.add(tripItem);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                refreshData();
            }

        }


    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            unclaimedTrips = null;
            refreshData();

        }
    }) {

       @Override
       public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
           HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
           return headers;
       };
    };


    // add the request object to the queue to be executed
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}


public void refreshData() {

    if (tripItems.isEmpty()) {
        mEmptyList.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mEmptyList.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);                   
    }

    adapter = new TripSelectAdapter(this, thisContext, tripItems);
    mTripList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to return something that it's not being filled yet, the call is asynchronous so it may take some time to fill the date into your `ArrayList<Cities>`, that's why it's empty.

You should remove this line `return cities;` and remember to create this `final ArrayList<Cities> cities=new ArrayList<>();` outside your method, and remove the return `ArrayList<Cities>` to a `void`.

And then, you can create a callback to notify that data is filled into your `ArrayList<Cities>`, if you are trying to populate these into a `RecyclerView` I recommend you to set the adapter in `onResponse()` method.

To do the callback thingy you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35739845/4385913) or this [`Gist`](https://gist.github.com/hhfa1990/077d46201ecee111e356)